# CURLOPT_POST, the request fails

Tags: php

I want to consume a web service by post method, and I have these fields:

[image]

and I am sending the information in this way;

```
  $post_fields = array('nombre' => 'uno', 'apellido' => 'dos');
```

PHP code:

```
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $post_fields ) );
  $resp = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  var_dump($resp);
```

But it does not bring me information. Does anyone know how to receive the data or what my error is?

Comment: What does the `var_dump` output exactly? Have you checked curl_error() output? Have you tried to get the HTTP headers? Have you used curl's verbose mode to see what's happening? There's a severe lack of debugging here, by the looks of it. We can't guess your problem just from staring at the code alone - you need to investigate it properly first.

Comment: Does the remote site use SSL? - if so you need parameters to negotiate correctly with the host. Does the remote host expect `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` payload? Using `http_build_query` sends the data as the former, sending just the array yields the latter encoding. Why is there no `useragent`  or other options in the request? The above seems devoid of many options I would usually expect to see in a request